# Flash upload keeps going after page refresh

Tags: php, flash, file-upload, actionscript-2

I have a rather strange problem, well strange to me.

I have a file upload tool that I created in flash (as2). The file uploads images and then writes the image details to a database. However, I seem to have a problem then when I refresh the page, the upload script keeps working.

And this seems to cause some issues with writing to the database when image don't actually appear to be on the server. I have fixed the issue by doing some checking to see if the file actually exists before writing to the server, but I would like to know why this happens.

Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could be because your swf is being cached by the browser with the process still running in the background. I would suggest you force the browser not to cache by adding this to the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a shot and let you know what happens